# Firebase Storage check if value is null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want delete image only when storageId is not null.

I checked for null like so and value is null but it's fired so exception says not found that image.

How can I check if it's null?

```
  const data = snapshot.data();
  const ref = firebase.storage().ref();
  if (data.storageId != null) {
    ref.child('images').child(`${data.storageId}.jpg`).delete();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null is falsey so

```
if (data.storageId) {
  ref.child('images').child(`${data.storageId}.jpg`).delete();
}
```

This will also cater for storageId is undefined.

Comment: false, 0, NaN, undefined, and empty string are also falsey as well.  How can you be certain here that the field is null, as the question asked? (Yes, Firestore has a specific value for null types.)